# Accuracy in Keras is larger than unity

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

When I train a Keras model, I get accuracy which is larger than unity:

```
975/975 - 820s - loss: 0.0381 - accuracy: 1.3000 - val_loss: 0.0183 - val_accuracy: 1.3060 - _timestamp: 1660558484.0000 - _runtime: 938.0000 - 820s/epoch - 842ms/step
```

Does anyone know how it is possible? Thank you!

Comment: You really need to add a lot more details in terms of code, we are not here to guess.

Comment: pretty sure that accuracy can't ben higher than 1

Comment: Perhaps you have missed activation functions or have not defined them in your model properly. Please post your model code for further assistance.